# How to set the mappings of a servlet so that it listens on the same path as CXF?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf, spring-ws

Dependencies from my pom:

2.2.5.RELEASE for Spring
3.3.5 for CXF

- spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-starter-actuator
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-devtools
- spring-boot-configuration-processor
- spring-boot-starter-tomcat
- spring-boot-starter-test
- cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws
- cxf-rt-features-logging

Here are the server settings defined in the application.yml:

```
server:
 port: 8080
 servlet:
  context-path: /cs
```

The first Servlet is a CXF JAXWS Endpoint configured like so:

```
// https://github.com/apache/cxf

@Bean(name=Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
public SpringBus springBus() {
    return new SpringBus();
}

@Bean
public IFileNetWSSoap documentService() {
    return new DocumentServiceEndpoint();
}

@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), documentService());
    endpoint.setServiceName(fileNetWS().getServiceName());
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation(fileNetWS().getWSDLDocumentLocation().toString());
    endpoint.publish(properties.getDocumentEndpoint());
    Binding binding = endpoint.getBinding();
    ((SOAPBinding)binding).setMTOMEnabled(true);
    return endpoint;
}
```

Currently listening at this address: **http://localhost:8080/cs/services/document-service_1.0**

The second Servlet is javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet (TomCat right now):

```
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/image-service_1.0"})
    public class ImageServiceEndpoint extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private BusinessService businessServices;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.businessServices.imageRetrieval(request, response);
    }
}
```

Currently listening at this address: **http://localhost:8080/cs/image-service_1.0**

And finally, there is the Spring-Boot Actuator Servlet.

Currently listening at this address: **http://localhost:8080/cs/actuator**

My question is "How can I configure the WebServlet to listen on the CXF segment without breaking everything?" e.g. **http://localhost:8080/cs/services/image-service_1.0**

It has been brought to my attention that maybe I should use a Spring MVC Controller in lieu of the Servlet. The only requirement I have for this endpoint id to take in query string parameters and stream binary content back to the caller.

Comment: You don't. A single mapping is for a single servlet, not for multiple.

Comment: @M.Deinum Any suggestions making look somewhat similar? Your advice has been spot on so far, thank you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Wonder if I can do this with cxf? The second service only has to be able to parse a query string as the params and stream an image back.

Comment: Why do you want them to be similar? They already share the context path, forthe remainder they are different endpoints. I also wonder why are you wrapping a controller (assuming an `@Controller`) in a servlet? That beats the purpose of the controller and Springs dispatcher servlet.

Comment: @M.Deinum ahh, that's what I wanted to hear. I chose a servlet because I was able to originally map it to a legacy .NET aspx page. I'm fine with an MVC or REST service, they're good at binding parameters too.

Comment: @M.Deinum ahhh, I see what you're referring too.. No, that's not a Spring Controller, it's the Business Logic Bean with a horrible name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't take over the same path as CXF WS Endpoint (default: /services)